Facing problem for displaying nested dropdown,when i move cursor to parent dropdown menu links it's not hitting my required mouseenter event
i'm using bootstrap v4.6 & angular v.14 and i'm facing problem for displaying nested dropdown.I'm displaying dropdown's inside flex container.I have dropdown-1 in that i have nested dropdown's,on cursor hover on dropdown-1 i'm displaying dropdown-1's dropdown menu and then when i move my cursor towards nested dropdowns (mouseenter) event hit and call that method "openDropdown(dropdown: string)" at that time inside string value should be that "dropdown-1-1" but showing that value "dropdown-1", so why is this not showing the required value while hitting the mouseenter event? and guide me what changes i have to make in my code for handling nested dropdown's,below is my code
Html Code
<div class="custom-container">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-12" (mouseenter)="openDropdown('dropdown-1')" 
      (mouseleave)="closeDropdown('dropdown-1')">
        <div class="dropdown-1 dropdown" [class.show]="dropdownStates['dropdown-1']">
          <a type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" (click)="toggleDropdown('dropdown-1')">
            All Categories
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" [class.show]="dropdownStates['dropdown-1']"> 
            
            <!-- Nested Dropdown for Shoes -->
            <div class="dropdown-submenu dropright" (mouseenter)="openDropdown('dropdown-1-1')" 
            (mouseleave)="closeDropdown('dropdown-1-1')">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Shoes</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" [class.show]="dropdownStates['dropdown-1-1']">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1 (Shoes )</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          
            <!-- Nested Dropdown for Sandals -->
            <div class="dropdown-submenu dropright" (mouseenter)="openDropdown('dropdown-1-2')" 
            (mouseleave)="closeDropdown('dropdown-1-2')">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Sandals</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" [class.show]="dropdownStates['dropdown-1-2']">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1 (Sandals)</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-1" (mouseenter)="openDropdown('dropdown-2')" 
      (mouseleave)="closeDropdown('dropdown-2')">
        <div class="dropdown-2 dropdown" [class.show]="dropdownStates['dropdown-2']">
          <a type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" (click)="toggleDropdown('dropdown-2')">
            Shoes 
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" [class.show]="dropdownStates['dropdown-2']">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Component Code
export class MyComponent {
  dropdownStates: { [key: string]: boolean } = {
    'dropdown-1': false,
    'dropdown-2': false,
    'dropdown-1-1': false, // Nested dropdown for Shoes
    'dropdown-1-2': false, // Nested dropdown for Sandals
  };

  private closeTimeout: any = null;

  openDropdown(dropdown: string) {
    if (this.closeTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.closeTimeout);
      this.closeTimeout = null;
    }

    // Close all other dropdowns
    for (const key in this.dropdownStates) {
      if (this.dropdownStates.hasOwnProperty(key) && key !== dropdown) {
        this.dropdownStates[key] = false;
      }
    }
    // Keep the main dropdown open when hovering over nested dropdowns
    if (dropdown.startsWith('dropdown-1-')) {
      this.dropdownStates['dropdown-1'] = true;
    }

    this.dropdownStates[dropdown] = true;
  }

  closeDropdown(dropdown: string) {
    this.closeTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      // Don't close the main dropdown if we're closing a nested one
      if (!dropdown.startsWith('dropdown-1-')) {
        this.dropdownStates['dropdown-1'] = false;
      }
      this.dropdownStates[dropdown] = false;
    }, 200); // Adjust the delay as needed
  }

  toggleDropdown(dropdown: string) {
    this.dropdownStates[dropdown] = !this.dropdownStates[dropdown];
  }
}

Css Code
/* Style for parent dropdowns */
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
}
.dropdown.show > .dropdown-menu
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(20px, 40px, 0px);
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    will-change: transform;
}
/* Style for nested dropdowns */

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
}
/* Show the nested dropdown menu when its state is true */
.dropdown-submenu.show .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 100%;
  }

I'm tried to display dropdown with nested dropdowns
